# How to implement point and sunlight OpenGL

Tags: opengl, lighting

I'm having trouble implementing both `point light` and `sunlight` in openGl upon a 3d pyramid. Do I need a separate `diffuse` component for the sunlight portion?

I'm also not sure how to go about implementing a `specular` component as well.

From my understanding it seems that both light sources will be mixed and sent to the shader, however I'm not sure how to implement them simultaneously.

Here is what I have for now.

```cpp
// GLEW header
#include <GL/glew.h> // This must appear before freeglut.h

// Freeglut header
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

// GLM header files
#include <glm/glm.hpp> 

#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp> 
//#include <glm/gtx/transform2.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_access.hpp>
//#include <glm/gtx/projection.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_inverse.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp> 

// Simple OpenGL Image Library header file
#include <SOIL.h>

// C++ header files
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(offset) ((GLvoid *) offset)



GLfloat pyramidVertices[][4] = {
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, // face 1
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f }, // face 2
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, // face 3
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, // face 4
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, // face 5
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, // face 6
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f }
};

int numVertices = 18;

GLfloat pyramidNormals[][4] = {
    { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, // normal 1
    { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, // normal 2
    { 0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { -0.0f, 0.4472f, 0.8944f, 1.0f }, // normal 3
    { -0.0f, 0.4472f, 0.8944f, 1.0f },
    { -0.0f, 0.4472f, 0.8944f, 1.0f },
    { -0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, // normal 4
    { -0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { -0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 0.4472f, -0.8944f, 1.0f }, // normal 5
    { 0.0f, 0.4472f, -0.8944f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 0.4472f, -0.8944f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, // normal 6
    { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }
};

GLfloat pyramidTextureCoords[][2] = {
    { 0.0319, 0.4192 }, // textureCoord 1
    { 0.3546, 0.0966 },
    { 0.3546, 0.4192 },
    { 0.4223, 0.5177 }, // textureCoord 2
    { 0.2541, 0.8753 },
    { 0.0996, 0.5116 },
    { 0.8047, 0.5250 }, // textureCoord 3
    { 0.6434, 0.8857 },
    { 0.4820, 0.5250 },
    { 0.6637, 0.0981 }, // textureCoord 4
    { 0.5130, 0.4184 },
    { 0.3748, 0.0926 },
    { 0.8416, 0.4227 }, // textureCoord 5
    { 0.6922, 0.0988 },
    { 0.9834, 0.0954 },
    { 0.0319, 0.4192 }, // textureCoord 6
    { 0.0319, 0.0966 },
    { 0.3546, 0.0966 }
};

// Update the texture image file path for your computer.
const char *imageFileName = "marble.jpg"; //This will apply the marble texture to the picture

// VBO buffer IDs
GLuint vertexArrayBufferID = 0;
GLuint normalArrayBufferID = 0;
GLuint texCoordArrayBufferID = 0;

GLuint program; // shader program ID

// Shader variable IDs
GLint vPos; // vertex attribute: position
GLint normalID; // vertex attribute: normal
GLint textureCoordID; // vertex attribute: texture coordinates

GLint mvpMatrixID; // uniform variable: model, view, projection matrix
GLint modelMatrixID; // uniform variable: model, view matrix
GLint normalMatrixID; // uniform variable: normal matrix for transforming normals
GLint lightSourcePositionID; // uniform variable: for lighting calculation
GLint diffuseLightProductID; // uniform variable: for lighting calculation
GLint ambientID;
GLint attenuationAID;
GLint attenuationBID;
GLint attenuationCID;
GLint textureSamplerID; // texture sampler ID

// Texture object ID
GLuint textureID;

// Texture unit ID
// These two values must be consistent. 
GLenum textureUnitID = GL_TEXTURE1;
// Sometimes, setting this to 0 will connect the sampler to any active texture unit. 
// But it's better to avoid using this "trick". 
GLuint textureSamplerValue = 1;

// Transformation matrices
mat4 projMatrix;
mat4 mvpMatrix;
mat4 modelMatrix;
mat4 viewMatrix;
mat3 normalMatrix;  // Normal matrix for transforming normals

// Light parameters
vec4 lightSourcePosition = vec4(0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
vec4 diffuseMaterial = vec4(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
vec4 diffuseLightIntensity = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
vec4 ambient = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
float attenuationA = 1.0f;
float attenuationB = 0.2f;
float attenuationC = 0.0f;

vec4 diffuseLightProduct;

// Camera parameters
vec3 eyePosition = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f);
vec3 lookAtCenter = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
vec3 upVector = vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
float fieldOfView = 30.0f;
float nearPlane = 0.1f;
float farPlane = 1000.0f;

// Mouse controlled rotation angles
float rotateX = 0;
float rotateY = 0;

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Initialize vertex arrays and VBOs
void prepareVBOs() {
    // Define a 3D pyramid. 

    // Get an unused buffer object name. Required after OpenGL 3.1. 
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexArrayBufferID);

    // If it's the first time the buffer object name is used, create that buffer. 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBufferID);

    // Allocate memory for the active buffer object. 
    // 1. Allocate memory on the graphics card for the amount specified by the 2nd parameter.
    // 2. Copy the data referenced by the third parameter (a pointer) from the main memory to the 
    //    memory on the graphics card. 
    // 3. If you want to dynamically load the data, then set the third parameter to be NULL. 
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidVertices), pyramidVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &normalArrayBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalArrayBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidNormals), pyramidNormals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create a buffer object to store the texture coordinates. 
    // Later we will passt his over to the shader. 
    glGenBuffers(1, &texCoordArrayBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordArrayBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidTextureCoords), pyramidTextureCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Print out the output of the shader compiler
void printLog(GLuint obj)
{
    int infologLength = 0;
    char infoLog[1024];

    if (glIsShader(obj)) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(obj, 1024, &infologLength, infoLog);
    }
    else {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(obj, 1024, &infologLength, infoLog);
    }

    if (infologLength > 0) {
        cout << infoLog;
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
void prepareShaders() {
    // Vertex shader source code
    // The vertex position and normal vector are transformed and then passed on to the fragment shader. 
    const char* vSource = {
        "#version 330\n"
        "in vec4 vPos;"
        "in vec4 normal;"
        "in vec2 vTextureCoord;"

        "uniform mat4x4 mvpMatrix;"
        "uniform mat4x4 modelMatrix;"
        "uniform mat3x3 normalMatrix;"

        "out vec4 transformedPosition;"
        "out vec3 transformedNormal;"
        "out vec2 textureCoord;"

        "void main() {"
        "   gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vPos;"
        // Transform the vertex position to the world space. 
        "   transformedPosition = modelMatrix * vPos;"
        // Transform the normal vector to the world space. 
        "   transformedNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal.xyz);"

        "   textureCoord = vec2(vTextureCoord.x, vTextureCoord.y);"
        "}"
    };

    // Fragment shader source code
    // A point light source is implemented. 
    // For simplicity, only the ambient and diffuse components are implemented. 
    // The lighting is calculated in world space, not in camera space. 

    // Note that the transformedPosition and transformedNormal in the fragment shader are for each fragment (pixel).
    // They are interpolated from the vertex positions and vertex normals in the (invisible) rasterization stage. 
    const char* fSource = {
        "#version 330\n"
        "in vec4 transformedPosition;"
        "in vec3 transformedNormal;"
        "in vec2 textureCoord;"

        "uniform vec4 lightSourcePosition;"
        "uniform vec4 diffuseLightProduct;"
        "uniform vec4 ambient;"
        "uniform float attenuationA;"
        "uniform float attenuationB;"
        "uniform float attenuationC;"

        "uniform sampler2D tex;"

        "out vec4 fragColor;"
        "void main() {"
        // Light direction
        "   vec3 lightVector = normalize(transformedPosition.xyz - lightSourcePosition.xyz);"
        // Distance between the light source and vertex
        "   float dist = distance(lightSourcePosition.xyz, transformedPosition.xyz);"
        // Attenuation factor
        "   float attenuation = 1.0f / (attenuationA + (attenuationB * dist) + (attenuationC * dist * dist));"
        // Calculate the diffuse component of the lighting equation.
        "   vec4 diffuse = attenuation * (max(dot(transformedNormal, lightVector), 0.0) * diffuseLightProduct);"

        "   vec4 textureColor = texture(tex, textureCoord);"

        // Combine the ambient component and diffuse component. 
        "   fragColor = mix((ambient + diffuse), textureColor, 0.6f);"
        "}"
    };

    // Declare shader IDs
    GLuint vShader, fShader;

    // Create empty shader objects
    vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Attach shader source code the shader objects
    glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &vSource, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &fSource, NULL);

    // Compile shader objects
    glCompileShader(vShader);
    printLog(vShader);

    glCompileShader(fShader);
    printLog(fShader);

    // Create an empty shader program object
    program = glCreateProgram();

    // Attach vertex and fragment shaders to the shader program
    glAttachShader(program, vShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fShader);

    // Link the shader program
    glLinkProgram(program);
    printLog(program);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Retrieve the IDs of the shader variables. Later we will
// use these IDs to pass data to the shaders. 
void getShaderVariableLocations(GLuint shaderProgram) {

    // Retrieve the ID of a vertex attribute, i.e. position
    vPos = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vPos");
    normalID = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "normal");

    // get the ID of the texture coordinate variable in the shader. 
    textureCoordID = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vTextureCoord");

    mvpMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvpMatrix");

    modelMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "modelMatrix");
    normalMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "normalMatrix");

    lightSourcePositionID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "lightSourcePosition");
    diffuseLightProductID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "diffuseLightProduct");
    ambientID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "ambient");

    attenuationAID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "attenuationA");
    attenuationBID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "attenuationB");
    attenuationCID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "attenuationC");

    // get the ID of the texture sampler in the shader. 
    textureSamplerID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex");
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
void setShaderVariables() {
    // value_ptr is a glm function
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(mvpMatrix));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(modelMatrix));
    glUniformMatrix3fv(normalMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(normalMatrix));

    glUniform4fv(lightSourcePositionID, 1, value_ptr(lightSourcePosition));
    glUniform4fv(diffuseLightProductID, 1, value_ptr(diffuseLightProduct));
    glUniform4fv(ambientID, 1, value_ptr(ambient));
    glUniform1f(attenuationAID, attenuationA);
    glUniform1f(attenuationBID, attenuationB);
    glUniform1f(attenuationCID, attenuationC);

    // Associate texture sampler ID in the shader with the active texture unit number.
    // glActiveTexture() function and glUniform1i(textUnit, ...) function calls must be consistent. 
    // If you change texture unit number in one function all, you must change the texture unit 
    // in the other function call. 
    glUniform1i(textureSamplerID, textureSamplerValue);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Set lighting related parameters
void setLightingParam() {
    diffuseLightProduct = diffuseMaterial * diffuseLightIntensity;
}

void prepareTextureImage() {
    // Use SOIL to load a picture. 
    textureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(imageFileName,
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y); // Adding SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS is also fine. 

    // Specify the current active texture unit number. 
    //
    // There are certain number of texture units on the graphics card (for example 32).
    // Check OpenGL extension viewer to find out how many texture units are on your card. 
    //
    // The shader accesses the texture through texture units, not the texture IDs. 
    // In other words, the shader does not know the texture IDs; it only sees 
    // (for example) 32 texture units.
    // You can have more than 32 texture images stored in the graphics card's memory, but
    // at any given time, the shader only sees 32 texture units. In the OpenGL program,
    // you can associate a texture unit with any texture ID, and change it at any time. 
    // This is how you can transfer potentially large numbers of texture images to the 
    // shader through a limited channel. 
    // 
    glActiveTexture(textureUnitID);

    // Bind the texture ID with the active texture unit number. 
    // In this case, texture ID "textureID" is associated with texture unit #2. 
    // When the shader reads texture unit #2, it will read the texture identified by ID textureID. 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Build the model matrix. This matrix will transform the 3D object to the proper place. 
mat4 buildModelMatrix() {

    mat4 rotationXMatrix = rotate(mat4(1.0f), radians(rotateX), vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    mat4 rotationYMatrix = rotate(mat4(1.0f), radians(rotateY), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    mat4 matrix = rotationYMatrix * rotationXMatrix;

    return matrix;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
void buildMatrices() {
    modelMatrix = buildModelMatrix();

    mvpMatrix = projMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix;

    normalMatrix = column(normalMatrix, 0, vec3(modelMatrix[0][0], modelMatrix[0][1], modelMatrix[0][2]));
    normalMatrix = column(normalMatrix, 1, vec3(modelMatrix[1][0], modelMatrix[1][1], modelMatrix[1][2]));
    normalMatrix = column(normalMatrix, 2, vec3(modelMatrix[2][0], modelMatrix[2][1], modelMatrix[2][2]));

    // Use glm::inverseTranspose() to create a normal matrix, which is used to transform normal vectors. 
    normalMatrix = inverseTranspose(normalMatrix);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Handles the display event
void display()
{
    // Clear the window with the background color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    buildMatrices();

    setShaderVariables();

    // Activate the shader program
    glUseProgram(program);

    // If the buffer object already exists, make that buffer the current active one. 
    // If the buffer object name is 0, disable buffer objects. 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBufferID);

    // Associate the vertex array in the buffer object with the vertex attribute: "position"
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPos, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    // Enable the vertex attribute: "position"
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPos);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalArrayBufferID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalID, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalID);

    // Associate the texture coordinate array in the buffer object with the vertex attribute "vTextureCoord", 
    // which is identified by texCoordID. 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordArrayBufferID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordID, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordID);

    // Start the shader program. Draw the object. The third parameter is the number of vertices. 
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);

    // Refresh the window
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Handles the reshape event
void reshape(int width, int height)
{
    // Specify the width and height of the picture within the window
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    projMatrix = perspective(fieldOfView, (float)width / (float)height, nearPlane, farPlane);

    viewMatrix = lookAt(eyePosition, lookAtCenter, upVector);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Read mouse motion data and convert them to rotation angles. 
void passiveMotion(int x, int y) {

    rotateY = (float)x * -0.5f;
    rotateX = (float)y * 0.5f;

    // Generate a dislay event to force refreshing the window. 
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
void init() {
    prepareVBOs();

    prepareShaders();

    getShaderVariableLocations(program);

    setLightingParam();

    prepareTextureImage();

    // Specify the background color
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("Texture mapping Demo");

    glutReshapeWindow(800, 800);

    glewInit();

    init();

    // Register the display callback function
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    // Register the reshape callback function
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    // Register the passive mouse motion call back function
    // This function is called when the mouse moves within the window
    // while no mouse buttons are pressed. 
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(passiveMotion);

    // Start the event loop
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: This topic is involved, but easy enough to understand if you first do the basic tutorials. Here are links to provide a great start for lighting.  https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Basic-Lighting and then https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Multiple-lights . This is way better than answer you will get here.

Comment: You have to sum the lights of the different light sources in the fragment shader. You have to provide the date of all light sources to the fragment shader and to do a separate computation for each light source in the fragment shader. Finally you can sum the fragment colors from the different light sources in the fragment shader. The more light sources, the brighter (whiter) it becomes.